# Is there a way to manipulate preprocessor define scope in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Just curious. Imagine I need to have a `#define A` that is the sum of n numbers, and those n numbers have a meaning I'd like to make explicit, but only for the computation of `A`, to improve readiblity,
instead of writing n macros or just writing `#define A <result_of_the_sum>`.
Is there a way I could limit the reach of these n `#define` directives to just the definition of A ? Just as in C one would do :

```
int a = 0;
{
int b = 1;
int c = 2;
int d = 3;
a = b + c + d;
} // end of b,c,d scope.
```

My intention is to have `A` defined when compiling but no definition for the other `n` defines used to compute `A`, since these would only be useful to understand the code better.
Edit:
Imagine I have these macros:

```
#define MEANINGFUL_NUMBER_1 1
#define MEANINGFUL_NUMBER_2 2
#define MEANINGFUL_NUMBER_3 3
```

And I have a macro, `A` that is the sum of them, and I like someone reading my code to understand the value of A not just see it defined straightforwardly, i.e. `#define A (MEANINGFUL_NUMBER_1 + ... + MEANINGFUL_NUMBER_N)`, such that only A is substituted before compilation but `MEANINGUL_NUMBER_*` is not.

Comment: Is `#define A (1+2+3)` good enough, or is there more to it?

Comment: 1, 2 and 3 would be numbers with a meaning that I'd like to make explicit in A's computation.

Comment: The only way to end the scope of a `#define` is to `#undef` it when you want the scope to end, but I think that puts you [well outside of rule #8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_of_10:_Rules_for_Developing_Safety-Critical_Code), and I would not recommend it.

Comment: I may be missing your point, but you can't `#define A` at compile time and then declare `int A ...` and assign a value at run-time unless you `#undef A` in between.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking but probably you don't want macros for your use case. Which _actual_  problem are you trying to resolve?

Comment: Yeah, the C example might be misleading. I meant to define A just as in C you would compute 'a'. My aim is to have something like a worksheet full of macros that are used to compute the to-be-used in the actual program macros.

Comment: @carce-bo don't describe what your question should be in a comment but instead [edit] your question and make clear what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is it better now ?

Comment: Not much. I still cannot figure out what problem you are trying to solve. One thing though, a macro does not do any computation. A macro does token replacement prior to compilation. And only very, very seldomly does a macro "improve" readability...

Comment: How about now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to manipulate preprocessor define scope in C

No.

> Is there a way I could limit the reach of these n #define directives to just the definition of A ?

No.

Note that macros are evaulated *upon use*. That means that everything has to be visible when the macro is used. You can `#undef` all the macros *after all usages*, ergo "limit the reach" in that way.

In C, there are no namespaces. In C use prefixes. You would do:

```
#define LIB_PRIV_B  1
#define LIB_PRIV_C  2
#define LIB_PRIV_D  3
#define LIB_A  (LIB_PRIV_B + LIB_PRIV_C + LIB_PRIV_D)
```

If you really do not want the numbers to leak into C, then use something to generate the C source code, which also gives you more power to the preprocessor side. Use jinja2, m4, php or python, and configure your build system to properly handle the generation dependency.